# How to create a shared service to be used in multiple Angular apps?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create a shared service to be used in multiple Angular app? if yes, **How?**

For example the way we create a angular library and we can use it externally from our app if we put it in a npm package. Can we achieve the same but only with a service so multiple apps can consume it?

E.g
I created service X

I have app A and app B

I want to inject via dependency injection service X in app A and B.

Comment: Of course. Why would that not be possible?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen awesome. any reference on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple direct answer is YES, you are looking for actually a **[`library`](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)** not a service.

The Angular Library Series - [`Creating a Library with the Angular CLI`](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

It's very similar to how you publish your shared package to NPM but Angular CLI  really made it super simple.

Comment: got it. When I run the command ```ng generate library tvmaze --prefix tm``` creates the library with multiple files. how can I create the service file only?

Comment: I have figured it out how to use the service. I just need to know how to create the service only when running the command above